# Dipole's electric field and potential at the equatorial plane

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, dipole

**The potential at the equatorial plane of the dipole is $0$**

**Again,The E at point at the the equatorial plane of the dipole is $\frac{-p}{4\pi\epsilon r^{3}}$**

But this [link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/efromv.html) says:
[image]

Then,why do not work  this equation in case of the equatorial plane of the dipole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $-p/(4 \pi \epsilon_0)$ is $E_z$, not $\vec{E}$.  $\vec{E}$ is a vector so you need to specific which component you're talking about.

At the equatorial plane, $V = 0$ but $E_z = -dV/dz \neq 0$.  You can have a function be zero at a point but its derivative not be 0.

Comment: But can the integration of -Eds be 0?

Comment: @ItachíUchiha I don't understand your question.  Integral over what path?

Comment: How can -\int_{a}^{b} Eds=\int_{a}^{b}dv=0 in the equatorial plane of dipole?

Comment: @ItachíUchiha It's a line integral $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{ds}$.  If the path of integration lies in the equatorial plane, then $\vec{E}$ is parallel to $\hat{z}$ and $\vec{ds}$ is perpendicular to $\hat{z}$, so their dot product is always zero, and the integral will be as well.